# How to implement the formula for the number of undirected $k$-cycles in a graph $G$?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

[This Wolfram MathWorld page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphCycle.html) said that,

[Giscard *et al.* "A General Purpose Algorithm for Counting Simple Cycles and Simple Paths of Any Length." 16 Dec 2016.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.05531.pdf) gave the formula for the number of undirected $k$-cycles in a graph $G$ as

$$
c_k=\frac{(-1)^k}{2 k} \sum_{H<\mathrm{conn} G}\left(\begin{array}{l}
|N(H)| \\
k-|H|
\end{array}\right)(-1)^{|H|} \operatorname{Tr}\left(\mathrm{A}_H^k\right)
$$

where the sum is over connected induced subgraphs $H$ of $G$, $N(H)$ denotes the number of the neighbors of $H$ in $G$ (namely vertices $v$ of $G$ which are not in $H$ and such that there exists at least one edge from $v$ to a vertex of $H$), $\operatorname{Tr} (\mathbf{A})$ denotes the matrix trace, and $\mathbf{A}_H^k$ is the $k$th matrix power of the adjacency matrix of the graph $H$.

---

My question is:

How to implement the formula using Mathematica?

Any help would be appreciated.

---

UPDATE

**I implement one snippet of Mathematica code by myself.
But the code fails on some test cases.
Can you correct the code? Any help would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 1):

I implement one by myself.

```mathematica
Clear["Global`*"];
Needs["IGraphM`"]


count1Cycles[g_Graph] := 
 List @@@ EdgeList[g] // Count[#, _?(#[[1]] == #[[2]] &)] &

count2Cycles[g_Graph] := 
 Map[#[[2]] &, EdgeList[g] // Tally] // Select[# >= 2 &] // 
   Map[Binomial[#, 2] &, #] & // Total

count3Cycles[g_Graph] := Tr[MatrixPower[AdjacencyMatrix[g], 3]]/6;

count4Cycles[g_Graph] := 
  Module[{A = 
     AdjacencyMatrix[g]}, (Tr[MatrixPower[A, 4]] + 
      Tr[MatrixPower[A, 2]] - 2*Total[VertexDegree[g]^2])/8];


count5Cycles[g_Graph] := 
 Module[{A = Normal@AdjacencyMatrix[g], A3, n = VertexCount[g]}, 
  A3 = MatrixPower[A, 
    3]; (Tr[MatrixPower[A, 5]] - 5*Tr[MatrixPower[A, 3]] - 
     5*Sum[(Sum[A[[i, j]], {j, 1, n}] - 2)*A3[[i, i]], {i, 1, n}])/10]
```

```mathematica
KhomenkoandGolovkoUndirectedKCycles[g_Graph, k_Integer] := 
 Module[{n, vertices, subsets, As, traceSum, i, binomialCoefficient, 
   sumOverI},
  
  If[k == 1, Return[count1Cycles[g]]];
  If[k == 2, Return[count2Cycles[g]]];
  n = VertexCount[g];
  vertices = VertexList[g];
  sumOverI = 0;
  For[i = 2, i <= k && i <= n, i++, 
   subsets = Subsets[vertices, {n - i}];
   traceSum = Sum[binomialCoefficient = Binomial[n - i, n - k];
     As = Normal@AdjacencyMatrix[g];
     As = DeleteRowsColumns[As, SubsetToIndices[vertices, subset]];
     binomialCoefficient*Tr[MatrixPower[As, k]], {subset, subsets}];
   sumOverI += ((-1)^(k - i))*traceSum;];
  sumOverI/(2*k)]

(*Helper function to delete rows and columns from a matrix*)

DeleteRowsColumns[matrix_, indices_] := 
  Module[{tempMatrix}, tempMatrix = matrix;
   (*Delete rows*)tempMatrix = Delete[tempMatrix, List /@ indices];
   (*Delete columns,transpose needed for column deletion*)
   tempMatrix = 
    Transpose[Delete[Transpose[tempMatrix], List /@ indices]];
   tempMatrix];

(*Helper function to convert a subset to indices based on the full \
set*)
SubsetToIndices[fullSet_, subset_] := 
 Flatten[Position[fullSet, #] & /@ subset]
```

```mathematica
GiscardetalUndirectedKCycles[graph_Graph, k_Integer] :=
 Module[{H, tr, numNeighbors, adjacencyMatrix, subgraphs, vertices, n},
  vertices = VertexList[graph];
  n = VertexCount[graph];
  adjacencyMatrix = AdjacencyMatrix[graph];
  subgraphs = Select[Subsets[vertices, {1, n}], ConnectedGraphQ[Subgraph[graph, #]] &];
  tr[A_, power_] := Tr[MatrixPower[A, power]];
  numNeighbors[H_] := Length@Complement[vertices, VertexList[H], Flatten[VertexList /@ NeighborhoodGraph[graph, #] & /@ VertexList[H]]];

  Switch[k,
   1, (* If k == 1*)
   count1Cycles[graph],
   
   2, (* If k == 2*)
   count2Cycles[graph],

   3, (* If k == 3*)
   count3Cycles[graph],

   4, (* If k == 4*)
   count4Cycles[graph],

   5, (* If k == 5*)
   count5Cycles[graph],
   
   _, (* Otherwise, use the formula *)
   Total[
    ((-1)^k / (2*k)) *
     Table[
      With[{H = Subgraph[graph, sg]},
       Binomial[numNeighbors[H], k - VertexCount[H]] *
        (-1)^VertexCount[H] *
        tr[AdjacencyMatrix[H], k]
       ], {sg, subgraphs}]
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

I have verified the Mathematica code , **it has passed these following test cases:**

```
n = 5;
g = CompleteGraph[n]
GiscardetalUndirectedKCycles[g, #] & /@ Range[1, n, 1]
KhomenkoandGolovkoUndirectedKCycles[g, #] & /@ Range[1, n, 1]


(* https://oeis.org/A284947 *)


Length /@ FindCycle[g, Infinity, All] // Tally
HighlightGraph[g, #]& /@ FindCycle[g, Infinity, All]
```

```
n = 3;
g = CompleteGraph[{n,n}]
GiscardetalUndirectedKCycles[g, #] & /@ Range[1, 2*n, 1]
KhomenkoandGolovkoUndirectedKCycles[g, #] & /@ Range[1, 2*n, 1]

Length /@ FindCycle[g, Infinity, All] // Tally
HighlightGraph[g, #]& /@ FindCycle[g, Infinity, All]
```

```
n = 3;
g = CompleteGraph[{n, n, n}]
GiscardetalUndirectedKCycles[g, #] & /@ Range[1, 3*n, 1]
KhomenkoandGolovkoUndirectedKCycles[g, #] & /@ Range[1, 3*n, 1]

Length /@ FindCycle[g, Infinity, All] // Tally
HighlightGraph[g, #]& /@ FindCycle[g, Infinity, All]
```

```
g = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 
   1 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 
   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2}]

GiscardetalUndirectedKCycles[g, #] & /@ Range[1, 10 , 1]
KhomenkoandGolovkoUndirectedKCycles[g, #] & /@ Range[1, 10 , 1]

Length /@ FindCycle[g, Infinity, All] // Tally
HighlightGraph[g, #]& /@ FindCycle[g, Infinity, All]
```

---

$$
\color{red}{\textbf{But the code fails on these test cases.}} \\
\color{red}{\textbf{Can you correct the code? Any help would be appreciated.}}
$$

```
n = 2;
g = GridGraph[{n, n, n}]
GiscardetalUndirectedKCycles[g, #] & /@ Range[1, n^3, 1]
KhomenkoandGolovkoUndirectedKCycles[g, #] & /@ Range[1, n^3, 1]

Length /@ FindCycle[g, Infinity, All] // Tally
HighlightGraph[g, #]& /@ FindCycle[g, Infinity, All]
```

```
n = 3;
g = GridGraph[{n, n}]
GiscardetalUndirectedKCycles[g, #] & /@ Range[1, n^2, 1]
KhomenkoandGolovkoUndirectedKCycles[g, #] & /@ Range[1, n^2, 1]

Length /@ FindCycle[g, Infinity, All] // Tally
HighlightGraph[g, #]& /@ FindCycle[g, Infinity, All]
```

```
n = 7;
g = WheelGraph[n]
GiscardetalUndirectedKCycles[g, #] & /@ Range[1, n, 1]
KhomenkoandGolovkoUndirectedKCycles[g, #] & /@ Range[1, n, 1]

Length /@ FindCycle[g, Infinity, All] // Tally
HighlightGraph[g, #] & /@ FindCycle[g, Infinity, All]
```